# Date picker in Html is not working as expected

Tags: html

I'm working on a requirement where date picker is displayed based on min and max dates when minimum and maximum are provided. But the format shows as attached [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKefR.png)

Requirement is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lITGD.png)

Below is the code snippet i have added HTML and TS.

```
 <mat-form-field>
     <input matInput type="date" [min]="todayDate [max]="maxReleaseDate" name='spoDate'
                        #spoDate="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="newSpoDate" autocomplete="off" required
                        [disabled]="spoPoCreateDate">
                    <mat-error *ngIf="spoDate && spoDate.untouched  && spoDate.invalid">This is required field
                    </mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
```

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Order } from 'app/general-component/models/order';
import { GetService } from 'app/general-component/services/get.service';
import { PostService } from 'app/general-component/services/post.service';
import { environment } from 'environments/environment.prod';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-spo-date-popup',
  templateUrl: './spo-date-popup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./spo-date-popup.component.css']
})
export class SpoDatePopupComponent implements OnInit {
  currentSpoDate: any;
  newSpoDate: any
  orderId: any;
  selectedOrganization: any;
  itemId: any;
  orderData: Order;
  todayDate: any;
  spoCreatePoDateNote: any;
  maxReleaseDate: any
  orderLineId: any;
  currentOrderId: any;
  loggedInUser: string;
  userGrantList: any;
  spoPoCreateDate: boolean;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private getService: GetService, private postService: PostService, private datePipe: DatePipe) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let date = this.datePipe.transform(new Date(), 'dd/MM/yyyy');
    this.todayDate = (date as string).split('/').reverse().join('-');
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(
      (params) => {
        this.orderId = params["orderId"];
        this.selectedOrganization = params["selectedOrganization"];
        this.itemId = params["ItemId"];
        this.orderLineId = params["OrderLineId"];
        this.currentOrderId = params["OrderId"];
        this.loggedInUser = params["loggedInUser"]
      },
      (error) => console.log("error" + error)
    )
    this.grantCheck();
    this.getService.getData(environment.getOrderByIdURL + this.currentOrderId, this.selectedOrganization).subscribe(res => {
      this.orderData = res as Order;
      if (this.orderData) {
        this.orderData.OrderLine.forEach((e) => {
          if (this.orderLineId === e.OrderLineId) {
            this.currentSpoDate = e.Extended.PODropDate ? e.Extended.PODropDate : "";
            this.maxReleaseDate = e.Extended.ReleaseDate ? this.datePipe.transform(new Date(e.Extended.ReleaseDate), 'yyy-MM-dd') : "";
            console.log("SPOPODATEPOPUP :: ", this.maxReleaseDate);

          }
        })
      }
    });

    let configData = {};
    this.getService.getData(`${environment.configStoreURL}/REST_EX01`, this.selectedOrganization).subscribe((res) => {
      let REST_EX01_CONFIG = res.ConfigStoreData;
      if (res.ConfigStoreData) {
        let list = REST_EX01_CONFIG.split(';');
        list.forEach(e => {
          let ex01Configs = e.split('=');
          configData = {
            ...configData,
            [ex01Configs[0]]: ex01Configs[1]
          }
        })
        // @ts-ignore
        this.spoCreatePoDateNote = configData.SPOPOCreateDateUpdateNote;
      }
    })
  }

  updateDate(res: any) {
    console.log(res);
    if (res && res.spoDate) {
      if (this.orderData && this.orderData.OrderLine) {
        let orderLineData = this.orderData.OrderLine.find((i) => i.OrderLineId === this.orderLineId);
        let isAllOLSame = this.orderData.OrderLine.every((e) =>
          e.OrderLinePromisingInfo && e.FulfillmentGroupId &&
          e.FulfillmentGroupId === orderLineData.FulfillmentGroupId &&
          e.OrderLinePromisingInfo.ShipFromLocationId === orderLineData.OrderLinePromisingInfo.ShipFromLocationId);
        this.orderData.OrderLine.forEach((e) => {
          if (this.orderLineId === e.OrderLineId) {

            e.Extended.PODropDate = this.datePipe.transform(res.spoDate, 'MM/dd/yyy');
            e.Extended.SPOPOCreateDateUpdated = true;
          } else {
            e.Extended.PODropDate = e.Extended.PODropDate;
            e.Extended.SPOPOCreateDateUpdated = e.Extended.SPOPOCreateDateUpdated;
          }
          if (isAllOLSame) {
            e.Extended.PODropDate = this.datePipe.transform(res.spoDate, 'MM/dd/yyy');
            e.Extended.SPOPOCreateDateUpdated = true;
          }
        })
        this.currentSpoDate = this.datePipe.transform(res.spoDate, 'MM/dd/yyy');
        this.saveOrder(this.orderData)
      }
    }
    // Extended.SPOPOCreateDateUpdated is flipped to true on updating
  }

  saveOrder(order: any) {
    // let saveOrder: any;
    // let postURL = environment.post_order_save;
    // saveOrder = this.postService.postData(postURL, this.selectedOrganization, order);
    this.postService.postData(environment.post_order_save, this.selectedOrganization, order)
      .switchMap((res) => {
        let data = {}
        return this.postService.postData(environment.rhFetaFocURL, this.selectedOrganization, data)
      })
      .subscribe(response => {
      },
        error => { throw error; }
      );
  }

  grantCheck() {
    this.getService.getData(environment.getUserGrant + this.loggedInUser, this.selectedOrganization).subscribe(response => {
      this.userGrantList = response;
      let spoPoCreateDateGrant = this.userGrantList.some((res) => {
        return res.ResourceId === "SPOPOCreateDateUpdate";
      })
      if (!spoPoCreateDateGrant) {
        this.spoPoCreateDate = true;
      } else {
        this.spoPoCreateDate = false
      }
      console.log('SPOPOCREATEDATE', this.spoPoCreateDate);
    });
  }

}
```

can anyone suggest how to fix?

Comment: How we can help you without see the code?

Answer (score 0):

This is might solve your problem

```html
<input type="date" value="2022-02-03" min="2022-02-03" max="2022-03-03">
```

Comment: After date selection i need input field to show dd/mm/yy

Comment: Can u plz explain in detail

Comment: After date selection and having both min and max dates i'm displaying with a variable. But input field should show dd/mm/yyyy, You can see in requirement image
after date selection without value attribute it displays dd/03/2022 from your suggestion but i want to display dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: Can u plz show the whole TS class